# Share sqlite database between native app and html5

Tags: ios, sqlite, html, share

I have a small native app for iPad with UIWebView only. This app can store data in SQLite database. Can I read this database in JS from web page inside the UIWebView?
Where does the browser store database files for SQLite? Could the database be shared between web page and native app?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can make requests to app from webview and get callback, us JS and UIWebViewDelegate
or any other

HTML:

```
<a href=\"http://commenter\">
```

in application:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *button = [[request URL] host];

    // if clicked on commenter/partager button in article
    if ([button isEqualToString:@"commenter"]) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this way of interaction between native app and web page. But the question is: "How can I use the same SQLite database from native app and from web page simultaneously?"

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the db or any other resource inside the ios app outside of it.

Because ios apps run in sandboxed environment. Each and every app is allocated some folder space it can put and get from that only for example documents directory, library directory

if you know some common scripting languages like php or classic asp you can do that easily.

for example

build a string with html tags, css and script

then load that string in webview

you can hide some data in hidden field and use it whenever you need it. If it needs to access some big sqlite data at the time just make a url request catch the url request in objective c and again build and load the string.